# Using reduce function on dom element objects

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dom

I'm trying to build a simple scatter plot in d3. In the chart I want to be able to get the text node in x axis ticks and do a summation of their automatically computed widths. For starter, i am trying to console log the same.

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3: Transitioning points to randomized values</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* No style rules here yet */
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click on this text to update the chart with new data values as many times as you like!</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 300;
    var padding = 30;

    //Dynamic, random dataset
    var dataset = []; //Initialize empty array
    var numDataPoints = 50; //Number of dummy data points to create
    var maxRange = Math.random() * 1000; //Max range of new values
    for (var i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++) { //Loop numDataPoints times
      var newNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange); //New random integer
      var newNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange); //New random integer
      dataset.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]); //Add new number to array
    }

    //Create scale functions
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })])
      .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })])
      .range([h - padding, padding]);

    //Define X axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(xScale)
      .ticks(5);

    //Define Y axis
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)
      .ticks(5);

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    //Create circles
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", 2);

    //Create X axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    //Create Y axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis);

    //GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE        
    console.log([...d3.selectAll(".x.axis").node().childNodes].slice(1).reduce(function(a, b) {
      console.log(a);
      return a.getBoundingClientRect().width + b.getBoundingClientRect().width
    }))

    //On click, update with new data   
    d3.select("p")
      .on("click", function() {

        //New values for dataset
        var numValues = dataset.length; //Count original length of dataset
        var maxRange = Math.random() * 1000; //Max range of new values
        dataset = []; //Initialize empty array
        for (var i = 0; i < numValues; i++) { //Loop numValues times
          var newNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange); //New random integer
          var newNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange); //New random integer
          dataset.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]); //Add new number to array
        }

        //Update scale domains
        xScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })]);
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
          return d[1];
        })]);

        //Update all circles
        svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xScale(d[0]);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yScale(d[1]);
          });



      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, i am getting the following error (at the console.log):

> Uncaught TypeError: a.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

What am i doing wrong here? I have already converted the nodeList to an array using ...spread operator so that should not be an issue.

Note: Stack overflow is not able to run my code for some reason so kindly use a separate HTML file to test this. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce's first return parameter is the accumulator, AKA what you're returning from your previous runs on reduce. That means on the second iteration "a" was 23.10938262939453 instead of a node.
Try something like this:

```
console.log([...d3.selectAll(".x.axis").node().childNodes].slice(1).reduce(function(a, b) {
  if(typeof a == 'number'){
    return a + b.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  }else
  return a.getBoundingClientRect().width + b.getBoundingClientRect().width
}))
```

If you wanted to make that cleaner, I would do this:

```
console.log([...d3.selectAll(".x.axis").node().childNodes].slice(1)
  .map(a=>a.getBoundingClientRect().width)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```

[stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-k2mzam?embed=1&file=index.html)

Comment: In general, what is the value of accumulator in first iteration? In this case I found out that initial value of accumulator is the first element in array (a node). Is it always the case?

Comment: Correct, since the initial accumulated value at iteration 0 will be array[0], or your starting node. However for the next loop of reduce the value is going to be what you returned the first run, in this case (a.getBoundingClientRect().width + b.getBoundingClientRect().width), which was your error.
For more information about any array functions, I can't reccomend Mozilla's stuff enough: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Thanks. Will surely have a look at this. Also, is there any way i can pass an initial value for accumulator as a number myself (so that we don't have to write 2 conditions in reduce) ? Something like this : `[...d3.selectAll(".x.axis").node().childNodes].slice(1).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b.getBoundingClientRect().width }, array[0].getBoundingClientRect().width)`                                         Here i am passing the width of first element as the default first argument.

Comment: The link above has this example, which returns 20 instead of 10 without an initial value: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) =>{return accumulator + currentValue;}, 10);`. I think that should fit your use case, yes.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: Reread your comment. In order to do that I'd instead to a .map(a => a.getBoundingClientRect().width).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b}). This maps all your nodes in the array to numbers, then retuces all of them to a singular value. I'll update the answer.

Comment: In my opinion, your original answer will be faster. Using both map and reduce aren't we traversing through same array twice? Best way (fast and clean) in my opinion:                                                                    `var axisTicks = [...d3.selectAll(".x.axis").node().childNodes];
        var initialValue = axisTicks[1].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        
        console.log(axisTicks.slice(2).reduce(function(a, b, c) {
            return a + b.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }, initialValue))`

Comment: Looks good to me. With smaller datasets like this ES6 makes it really easy for your inner functions for map and reduce to things like `const getWidth = x => x.getBoundingClientRect().width;` and then all you'd have to do is call `array.map(getWidth);` thanks to currying, making your code easier to read and test. If you production dataset is going to be bigger then it yes may cause concern, tl;dr readability vs testability vs speed, milage may vary.